# Yii CActiveDataProvider Join and select from joined table

Tags: yii

I have the following example code:

```
                $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('firstTable', 
                    array('criteria' => array(
                        'select' => 't.firstfield,secondTable.secondfield',
                        'join' => 'join secondTable on secondTable.id=t.secondTable_id',
                    ),
                    'pagination' => array(
                        'pageSize' => 10,
                    ),
                ));
                $results=$dataProvider->getData();
```

After running the code above, firstField (from the model table - firstTable) is available in the object, but secondField (from the joined table - secondTable) is not.

Can anyone provide assistance on what is wrong with the code or why the "select" option is not picking up the secondField?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it would be better if you use CDbCriteria, that has a better solution to join table with the help of relations. I can show the example with CDbCriteria.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 'firstfield';
$criteria->with = array('secondTable_relation'=>array('select'=>'secondfield'));
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('firstTable', 
                    array('criteria' => $criteria,
                    'pagination' => array(
                        'pageSize' => 10,
                    ),
                ));
                $results=$dataProvider->getData();
```

secondTable_relation is a relation name with secondTable.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone provide assistance on what is wrong with the code or why the "select" option is not picking up the secondField?

#### Answer:

That is happening because you have not selected the field which relates the two tables, i.e the foreign key in firstTable : `secondTable_id`. So if you do:

```
'select' => 't.firstfield,t.secondTable_id,secondTable.secondfield',
```

you will be able to access the secondField of secondTable:

```
$singleresultrow->secondTableRelationName['secondField'];// a single result row can be obtained by foreach iteration over $results
```

However there will still be another query (**Lazy Loading**) when you access the secondField. And the initial(before lazy) object returned will not have the secondTable object filled.

The problem i think lies in the fact that **by default** yii accesses the related fields by lazy loading, and for that to happen the related *foreign_key* should be present in the model you are trying to make a dataprovider of, here it is firstTable, and the foreign_key `secondTable_id`.

Comment: and i also agree with onkarjanwa, that it would be better to use the [`with`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#with-detail)